# Dynamically add and remove input fields are working, but values not showing up in Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-sheets

After watching several YouTube vids, I've managed to set up a HTML based Form in which respondents can dynamically add or remove fields (or line items). The initial look of the form is almost the exact way as what I intended to have, however in the google sheet, only the first row of input data was captured, while the data of the added rows are not being recorded. 
I'm almost certain that it is because the name of each input field was set to "entry.xxxxxx" as shown in one of the tutorial vids, which is why google sheet is only capturing the first data of the input field.

If this is the case, is there anyway I should amend the codes to allow respondents to add or remove input fields, while at the same time have all of the responses recorded in Google Sheet? Thanks in advance!

```
<html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Price Reports</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
      <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSd8tF03ZHPVWyBT38x37tMkPGSuGL9P02K6vJP_sXlaetpDyA/formResponse" target="_self" method="POST">
           <div class="container"> 
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <h2 align="center">Price Reports</h2>  
                <div class="form-group">  
                     <form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
                          <div class="table-responsive">  
                               <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field"> 
                                 <tr><td><input type="text" name="entry.368335800" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                                     <td><input type="text" name="entry.588917263" placeholder="Added by" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                                     <td><input type="text" name="entry.1340057160" placeholder="Consultant" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                                     <td><input type="text" name="entry.1318147509" placeholder="Company Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                    <tr>  
                                         <td><input type="text" name="entry.1748634530" placeholder="Commodity" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="entry.1662440771" placeholder="Origin Country" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="entry.1892106366" placeholder="Deal Type" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="entry.1829905809" placeholder="Price" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="entry.1538189357" placeholder="Destination Country" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                                         <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
                                    </tr>  
                               </table>  
                               <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
                          </div>  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
        </form>   
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="Commodity[]" placeholder="Commodity" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="Origin Country[]" placeholder="Origin Country" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="Deal Type[]" placeholder="Deal Type" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="Price[]" placeholder="Price" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="Destination Country[]" placeholder="Destination Country" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
      $('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSd8tF03ZHPVWyBT38x37tMkPGSuGL9P02K6vJP_sXlaetpDyA/formResponse",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your other rows are not being submitted because the `name` of the form element is not properly configured. It should be of the style `entry.xxxxxx` as you do with your other entries, ie. `entry.1538189357` however you are sending it as strings such as `Commodity[]`.

Furthermore, you are attempting to send multiple rows of information with only one submit request. That is not possible.

Instead, you should:

1. Prevent the form from issuing the default request. You will instead issue multiple requests from JavaScript code using jQuery's ajax. To avoid this default behaviour, you can use [preventDefault()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp);
2. Set up an `onClick` event on the form submit button. The code assigned to it will get the data of the form. You will need to get the common fields (in your case `date`, `Added by`, `Consultant`, `Company name`) and then the individual row fields. Afterwards, send multiple requests (with the appropriate name & value keys - using the proper `entry.xxxxxx` values) each containing the individual row data and the common data.